# Linux PCB with support for GPU accelerated X Windows

Tags: pcb, arm, linux, gpu

I'm looking for a Linux PCB (ARM or Intel) 
with a GPU that can run debian linux and use the GPU in X Windows. 
Preferably with an HDMI output or at least a DVI output.

Something that is available on the market today.
I'm located in China, so I should be able to find just about anything,
but I have no idea what to look for.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Start by looking at Raspberry Pi, Beagle Board and Beagle Bone

Comment: The problem with the Raspberry PI (of which I have a few laying around) is that there is no GPU support in X yet in any of the distro's otherwise it would have been perfect

Comment: *disclaimer: the face in OP's avatar is **not** representative for Belgians in general* :-)

Comment: ??? I don't get it :p

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest the MK802, or some otherboard like that built around the Allwinner A10, but AFAIK, the Mali 400 used on the board is still not supported by the Linux distros available for it, just the built-in Android...

There is also the Mele A2000, a media box that has more features, it is a complete computer featuring even SATA - and the Allwinner A10.

I recentlz found a more hackable board, that exposes some GPIO pins too, but I can't find it now...

[Distros on MK802](http://liliputing.com/2012/07/linux-distributions-that-can-run-on-an-mk802-mini-pc.html)

Comment: Yep, been thinking about that as well, just recently found a dual core version on the market here, but I have yet to confirm it's real

Comment: The UG802 can not run linux as per now... I also found that, but the Rockchip SoC is not as open to Linux as the Allwinner is...

Answer (score 1):

Probably most popular GPU in ARM processors is Mali-400. Check Origen board with Samsung Exynos: http://www.origenboard.org/

Answer (score 1):

While I cannot say for sure how good the X performance is, I know that it was definitely usable with the IMX 6 series boards from freescale semiconductor.

http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/taxonomy.jsp?code=IMX6X_SERIES

They have a dev kit I believe runs around $99.

We use it at work for simulated glass cockpit displays and it has impressive OpenGL ES 2.0 performance.

There are several root filesystems available including Ubuntu.